# Adding Address Values Properly in C

Tags: c

Take the following C code as an example:

```
    char buffer1[5];
    int* ret;
    printf("Buffer1 is: %x\n", (int*)buffer1);
    ret = (int*)buffer1 + 12;
    printf("Ret is: %x\n", ret);
```

I just want to add 12 bytes to buffer1 and store it in ret. This is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to properly add hex address in C. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not at all clear what your goal is here.  Please explain a goal, and write an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add 12 *bytes,* you need a data type that work on byte boundaries, like a `char *`. Now you may *think* you're doing that (`buffer1` decays to a `char *`) but, because a cast binds more tightly than an addition, `(int*)buffer1 + 12` actually means `((int*)buffer1) + 12` rather than `(int*)(buffer1 + 12)`.

And the problem with adding 12 to an `int *` is that it scales the addition. If your `int` is four bytes, adding 12 to it will actually add 48 bytes.

If you change the assignment line to:

```
ret = (int*)(buffer1 + 12);
```

you will find that the addition happens to `buffer1` so will not be scaled, then the cast to an `int *` will operate on that value.

I should mention of course that *dereferencing* the resultant pointer is probably not a good idea since it will be beyond the bounds of the actual array.

I'll also suggest that `%p` is probably a better format string to use for pointers.

Comment: Oh this was mean to illustrate stack overflows so thats why I'm adding all the way to the end of the buffer's memory address.

Comment: @BhubhuHbuhdbus, if you want a simpler stack overflow, just use `char buffer[1]; strcpy (buffer, "this string is way to big to go into that buffer");`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ret = (int*) (buffer1 + 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = (int *)(buffer1 + 12);
```

should do the trick. An `int *` plus `something`, looks at that `something` added to the initial address as at `sizeof(int) * something` (standard pointer arithmetic).